# JavaScript not parsing JSON properly in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
{"status":"success","responseMesg":"{\"totalDomains\":1,\"accepted\":0,\"rejected\":0,\"errors\":\"[{\\\"errorMessage\\\":\\\"Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded\\\",\\\"domainEventId\\\":\\\"119\\\"}]\"}"}
```

Above the response of a service call. I used angular.fromJson to convert this to a JSON. I was able to access accepted, rejected, status, totalDomains, responseMesg properly. But I'm not able to access errorMessages. When I print errors, I see following

```
[{"errorMessage":"Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded","domainEventId":"119"}]
```

Which looks like an array. But I'm not able to access individual objects in this array of objects like if `arr` is the array then I want to access `arr[0].errorMessage`, but not able to. It prints `undefined`. When I do `arr.length`, it printed 93. Is this just getting treated as string ? How to solve ?

Comment: did you try this  err[0] ?

Comment: Yes I tried. Did not work. It printed undefined.

Comment: arr.err[0].errorMessage will work

Comment: That did not work as well.

Comment: Looks like there's an extra level of escaping from somewhere.

Comment: But when I print data.responseMesg.errors, it did not show any escapes. I have put the output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your serializing your JS objects to JSON on couple of levels. Here's why:

`responseMesg` is just a string, and your JSON after parsing looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "responseMesg": "{\"totalDomains\":1,\"accepted\":0,\"rejected\":0,\"errors\":\"[{\\\"errorMessage\\\":\\\"Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded\\\",\\\"domainEventId\\\":\\\"119\\\"}]\"}"
}
```

Now you need to parse `responseMesg` to JSON separately, here's the output:

```
{
    "totalDomains": 1,
    "accepted": 0,
    "rejected": 0,
    "errors": "[{\"errorMessage\":\"Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded\",\"domainEventId\":\"119\"}]"
}
```

Next step is to parse `errors` which is again, only a string. Parsing will give you this:

```
[
    {
        "errorMessage": "Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded",
        "domainEventId": "119"
    }
]
```

I have checked and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and `angular.fromJson` are giving me exactly the same output, so you could try this:

```
var a = angular.fromJson({"status":"success","responseMesg":"{\"totalDomains\":1,\"accepted\":0,\"rejected\":0,\"errors\":\"[{\\\"errorMessage\\\":\\\"Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded\\\",\\\"domainEventId\\\":\\\"119\\\"}]\"}"});
a.responseMesg = angular.fromJson(a.responseMesg);
a.responseMesg.errors = angular.fromJson(a.responseMesg.errors);
console.log(a);
```

To avoid it in the future construct your JS object fully (without serializing) and then serialize the whole thing. If you don't have a control over nested serializing, try deserialize while constructing your response, if you detect a string.

Try using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try the solution you gave before posting this question, but definitely did some thing wrong while printing the value. This solution worked though. How do I deserialize ?

Comment: @TechCrunch `angular.toJson` serialize data (`Object` -> `string`), `angular.fromJson` deserialize data (`string` -> `Object`). So when you create your `response` and expect object or array, check whether data is just a string (`angular.isString`) and run `angular.fromJson` on it. Your `responseMseg` and `errors` are being returned as strings (already serialized) and not as objects as you would expect. And then they get just escaped...

Comment: @TechCrunch So if you have control over `responseMseg` and `errors`, and the way how they're returned, simply change it to be an `object` and not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

you json is not correct 
the correct json is

```
    {
  "status": "success",
  "responseMesg": {
    "totalDomains": 1,
    "accepted": 0,
    "rejected": 0,
    "errors": [
      {
        "errorMessage": "Could not connect to XRP, max retry count exceeded",
        "domainEventId": "119"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```